# Ajax stops working when logged in?

Tags: ajax, warnings

I have implemented ajax in the website

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wppl_function', 'wppl_function ');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wppl_function', 'wppl_function');
```

But this works without any issue if i log out.

This is the error that i am getting the console

```
component : "Core"
file : "wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php"
line : 286
message : "call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_ajax_wppl_function' not found or invalid function name"
stack : ["do_action('wp_ajax_wppl_function')"]
type : "warning"
```

Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things that I see:

1. There's a space in your first add_action declaration.  Should be `add_action('wp_ajax_wppl_function', 'wppl_function');`
2. Have you declared wppl_function to run it?
3. Have you localized your scripts when logged in?  Please review [the codex entry on wp_ajax_nopriv (action)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action))